# Running Javascript(in Chrome) after I redirect to a new URL on the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, url

I'm trying to make a simple bot that based on some conditions redirects me to a new URL on the same tab and clicks a button automatically. I have everything working dandy but when I get redirected to this new tab my code disappears and everything is reset. The redirect is all on the same domain. By the way I'm putting this code into the console in Chrome if that helps anything.

```
var a = URL
window.location.replace(a) //Redirects to a given URL and clears the console
$("input[type='submit']").click() //Doesn't get executed due to console being cleared
```

If there is no "clear cut" way to do this is there anyway I can work around this? If you need anymore information I'll be happy to provide it.

Edit: I tried using iframe to solve this but just threw an error which based off some google searches can't be solved.

Refused to display 'www.tacos.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to execute this code in separate statements (execute your last line after the second page loads).  Also, it may help to right-click in the console and choose "Preserve log upon navigation".

If you take this code out of the console, it won't work.  You may be able to load the new page in an `<iframe>` and run the javascript against the document in the frame.

Comment: how can I wait for the next page load to automatically execute rest of the code from the console? adding eventListener add it to current page not next page

Answer (score 0):

When you change the url, your page is redirected so your code stops executing. The solution would depend on whether the page is on your domain, as a solution would be an iframe, but if the url is off-domain, you will run into security issues if you try to fire the button from outside of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could get that is by:

- Using `$("input[type='submit']").click()` on the page that will be presented.
- Use ajax and replace the current page with the url's content. Be aware of using jquery's `live()`

Comment: What do you mean by your first suggestion? Do you mean just typing it in console again to click it? Also for your second suggestion I'm a bit lost in two ways. Wouldn't doing that not "truly" click the button on the "button page" but copy the html of the "button page" and just pasting it in my current page and clicking a fabricated button? This is partially my fault if it is true as I didn't include that when I click this button it will buy a "virtual object" in a game. Sorry if that was a bit confusing; not very good at explaining things.

Comment: Well that's the only way you can do if the page is not of your domain. If it is on your domain, you can create an iFrame and do whatever you want inside of it.

Comment: Alright looking into what you suggested with replacing the HTML of the webpage and it looks pretty promising; thank you. Sorry to keep bugging you but what is wrong with this code? It keeps adding HTML on the end of the link. [Link](http://pastebin.com/JAYkvHve) Again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a querystring to the url that is parsed on a document load event and does your click action.

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by a query string. Wouldn't that just turn everything into one giant string? Could you explain what this would do(I get the document load part)? Thank you.

Comment: A url normally looks like: "http:\\www.google.com\" a url with a querystring looks like: "http:\\www.google.com\?val=1" and you can use javascript on your page to read the querystrings and do something if the correct value was set.

Comment: You could use something like this to parse the querystrings: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Comment: Alright after some studying on that topic I think I grasp the basics. I toyed around with it and basically understand that based on what is in the url you can return their "value" for instance, if I put in getQueryVariable(expectedPrice) for example.com/expectedPrice=20 it would return 20. So effectively based on the url I can do something if the values are right. I might be missing something but how does this help exactly? If I got a url from my bot and I wanted to click a button on that url wouldn't I still have to go to that page to click it; therefor stopping my code?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the question, I was thinking that you were in control of the url being redirected to, is this correct?

Comment: If you do not own the document being redirected to, I'm afraid there is no way to do this in javascript. There are measures put in place in browsers to prevent javascript from an outside source being run on a page. It's a Cross-Site-Scripting problem.  You could consider using C# and Selenium (or I'm sure various others) to accomplish the same thing from outside the browser.